# Jquery only activate current row button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 buttons to expand and shrink a subtable at a specific row. The buttons will change from a + to a - when clicked. Currently when I click on a button, the correct row shows up. However, all the buttons turn into a -. May I know how I can limit the button to the current row only.

This is my code

```
$('.expandlink').on('click', function () {
    var curr_row = $(this).parent().parent('tr').attr('data-id');

    $(".subtable").each(function () { //loop through each row
        if ($("[type='hidden']", this).val() == curr_row) {
            $(this).show();
            $('.expandlink').hide();
            $('.shrinklink').show();
        }
    });
});

$('.shrinklink').on('click', function () {
    var curr_row = $(this).parent().parent('tr').attr('data-id');

    $(".subtable").each(function () {
        if ($("[type='hidden']", this).val() == curr_row) {
            $(this).hide();
            $('.shrinklink').hide();
            $('.expandlink').show();
        }
    });
});
```

```
<tbody>
<?php $offset = $this->uri->segment(4,0)+1; ?>
<?php foreach($user as $row): ?>
<tr data-id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
<td><?php echo $offset++; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->company; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->firstname; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->lastname; ?></td>
<td><input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ? >"/><input type="button" class="expandlink" value="+"/></td>
<td><input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/><input type="button" class="shrinklink" value="-"/></td>
<td><input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/><input type="hidden" name="company" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/><input type="hidden" name="set" value="edit"/><input type="button" class="editlink" value="Edit"/></td>
<td><input type="hidden" class="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/> <input type="hidden" name="company" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/><input type="hidden" name="set" value="delete"/><input type="button" class="deletelink"  value="Delete"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="subtable">
    <td><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"/></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->company; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->firstname; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->lastname; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Who do you get in the console log.?

Comment: I haven't output anything in the console log. But so far based on the sub tables that have appeared, the ID's are being picked up correctly

Comment: `$("[type='hidden']")` to `$("input[type='hidden']")`

Comment: I can't really change it as I am getting the value from the current row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the parent row first then specify to it's childrens

```
$(this).parents("tr").find('.expandlink').hide();
$(this).parents("tr").find('.shrinklink').show();
```

Edit:
After reading your table structure only noticed that the subtable is in different `<tr>` tag

```
$('.expandlink').on('click', function () {
    var curr_row = $(this).parent().parent('tr').attr('data-id');
    var row = $(this).parents("tr");
    $(".subtable").each(function () { //loop through each row
        if ($("[type='hidden']", this).val() == curr_row) {
            $(this).show();
            row.find('.expandlink').hide();
            row.find('.shrinklink').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This one only expands it. The shrink button doesn't show though?

Comment: Sorry, tried modifying this and the show still doesnt work